# No more UI thread hell in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

It used to be a hell of operating UI control from another thread in MFC and WinForm. I really hated it.

In WPF it's still a pain but much less: When using MVVM and data bindings, all I need to do is to update the VM, either form UI thread or my background thread. I nearly operate the UI controls in my threads. Of course thread synchronization is still a matter, but no more UI thread specific problems.

I happened to realize it just now, but I was wondering: am I right? anything I missed?

Thanks

Comment: -1, bad question, come back when you find concrete issue :)

Comment: If your types implement INotifyPropertyChanged, yes.  DependencyProperties, ObservableCollections<T>, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also access all UI elements by using the Dispatcher of the window from another thread:

```
windowObj.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
{
    // Do some changes on the window, like changing textbox content, ...
    // TextBox1.Text = "test";
});
```

In WPF it is much easier to sync the different threads, as you said the MVVM pattern is great step forward in that regard

Answer (score 1):

Every UI interaction should happen in UI thread. So, basically, this code won't work:

```
public class Context
{
    public Context()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                Items.Add("Test item")));
            }
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And this one will:

```
public class Context
{
    public Context(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Items.Add("Test item")));
            }
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```